# AJAX querystring in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, query-string

I'm trying to use AJAX to pass a querystring within wordpress, I've tried various code on the net using get and post.  However I'm unable to get the parameter within my PHP.

Using javascript within my page works, however it posts back the page which I want to avoid.  Any suggestions?

working code with postback:

```
self.location = "?q=" + postcode;
```

or

```
jQuery.param.querystring(location.href= "?q=" + postcode);
```

ajax query using $_POST['q'] in php doesn't get the parameter

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ,
        data: {"q": postcode},
        success: function(data){jQuery('#results').val(postcode);}
    });
```

Thanks

Gemma

Still having issues with this, can't get my querystring into my php:

```
class PostcodeChecker extends WP_Widget {
      function PostcodeChecker() {
                $widget_ops = array(
                'classname' => 'PostcodeChecker',
                'description' => 'Checks if valid postcode in database before request button enable'
      ); 

      $this->WP_Widget(
                'PostcodeChecker',
                'Postcode Checker',
                $widget_ops
      );
```

}

```
      function widget($args, $instance) { // widget sidebar output
                extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
                echo $before_widget; // pre-widget code from theme
                print ('<h2 class="blocktitle">Postcode Checker</h2> ');
                print ('<input type="text" id="txtPostcode"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="btnRegister" type="button" disabled="disabled" value="request application form" />');

                print ('<br/><input type="text" id="results"></div><br/>');
                $postcode = $_GET['q'];

                print $postcode;
                $mysqli= mysqli_connect('localhost','root', 'My5ql5s5s');

                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                    exit();
                }

            // A QUICK QUERY ON A FAKE USER TABLE
                $query = "SELECT * FROM db_wp_webteam1.wp_bduk_towns where town_postcode='BT11ER'";
                $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);


            // GOING THROUGH THE DATA
                if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    //while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    //  echo stripslashes($row['town_postcode']);   
                    //}
                    echo 'Results found';
                }
                else {
                    echo 'NO RESULTS';  
                }

            // CLOSE CONNECTION
                mysqli_close($mysqli);

                echo $after_widget; // post-widget code from theme
      }
```

}

```
function add_js_to_wp_footer(){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#txtPostcode').keyup(function(){
    var postcode = jQuery(this).val();
    postcode = postcode.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    if (postcode.length >= 5)
    {
    //self.location = "?q=" + postcode;
    jQuery('#txtPostcode').keyup(function(){
    var postcode = jQuery(this).val();
    postcode = postcode.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    if (postcode.length >= 5)
    {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ,
        data: {"q": postcode},
        success: function(data){jQuery('#results').val(data);}
    });
    }
return false;
});

    }
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: The ajax is putting the code into a text box, however I need to use it to make a query on a database

Comment: Replacesuccess: function(data){jQuery('#results').val(postcode);} with success: function(data){jQuery('#results').val(data);}

Comment: still having issues, see above for full code

Comment: can you post what error u getting